# Dynamic circle in Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Using the Attached Fiddle we could see the circle is created on mouse up. Right now, it is drawing the circle by choosing the mouse up point. So, wherever we our mouse up position, the circle will be created there.

**[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/kneDX/1589/)**

```
<div id="canvas">Click to draw<br/></div>
```

I am actually trying to create a circle starting from mouse down point till mouse up point.

Please suggest

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kneDX/1590/

Comment: something like this i guess http://jsfiddle.net/8YSxh/

Comment: **[There is some problem with Radius calculation](http://screencast.com/t/t2bjPT4bK7l)**